# display data to table horizontally asp sql

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So I have a data that I got from the database that I want to display horizontally in my asp page. It is like a transpose option in Excel.

Here is how my data is currently displayed.

```
Call # | Greetings # | Verifying Information # | Hold Protocol #  |
Call 1 | Greetings 1 | Verifying Information 1 | Hold Protocol  1 | 
Call 2 | Greetings 2 | Verifying Information 2 | Hold Protocol  2 |
Call 3 | Greetings 3 | Verifying Information 3 | Hold Protocol  3 |
```

But I want to display it like this.

```
  Call #          | Call 1           | Call 2           | call 3
  Greeting #      | Greeting 1       | Greeting 2       | Greeting 3
  Verifying#      | Verifying 1      | Verifying 2      | Verifying 3
  Hold Protocol#  | Hold Protocol 1  | Hold Protocol 2  |  Hold Protocol 3
```

And here is my code for displaying the data

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered table-scores">
            <tr>
                <td>Call #</td>
                <td>Greetings</td>
                <td>Verifying Information</td>
                <td>Hold Protocol</td>
            </tr>

            <% 
            if not RsAgent.eof then
                do while not RsAgent.eof
            %>

                <tr>
                    <td> <% response.write("Call ") %>> </td>
                    <td> <% response.write(greeting) %> </td>
                    <td> <% response.write(verify) %> </td>
                </tr>
            <%  
                    ctr =ctr+1
                    RsAgent.movenext
                    loop

                    end if 
                end if  
            %>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetRows Recordset's method to retrieve the records into an array and then print the data as you like.

This is an example:

```
<table>
<%
  titles = Array("Call #", "Greetings #", "Verifying Information #", "Hold Protocol #")
  data = rsAgent.GetRows()
  For i=0 To 3
%>
    <tr>
      <th><%=titles(i)%></th>
    <% For j=0 To UBound(data,2) %>
      <td><%=data(i,j)%></td>
    <% Next j %>
    </tr>
<% Next i %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is something like this.

```
<tr>
    <td>Call#</td>

<% while not RsAgent.eof %>
    <td><% response.write("call") %></td>
<% RsAgent.movenext %>
<% wend %>

</tr>

<% RsAgent.movefirst %>

<tr>
    <td>Greetings</td>

<% while not RsAgent.eof %>
    <td><% response.write("greeting") %></td>
<% RsAgent.movenext %>
<% wend %>
</tr>
```

and so on...

Comment: While this'll *work*, it'll be sloooooowwwww. I wouldn't suggest using it unless you have way more rows than columns.